# call a method in JNSI that it's inner method located at the server package

Tags: java, gwt

I have tried to do:

```
  package com.mycompany.myapp.client;

  public class MyUtiliity {

    public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
       $wnd.getQuestions=$entry(@com.mycompany.myapp.server.action.QuestionAction::getQuestions());
       $wnd.main();
    }-*/;

  }
```

but i get an error when compiling:

Referencing class 'com.mycompany.myapp.server.action.QuestionAction' : unable to resolve class

Comment: **Remember** In GWT you can't access server side classes at client side directly.

Answer (score 3):

A JSNI method is code written directly in JavaScript, the GWT equivalent of "native code", and it runs on the client, inside the browser's JavaScript engine. There is no server code available to call. If you need to query the server for content, you'll need to use an RPC mechanism like GWT-RPC or regular AJAX.